# obj-c return block NSString to c++ after request

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, httprequest, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to get this data correctly back to c++, but there are some random crashes. I want to access the data in C++. Sometimes it does, sometime it doesn't. I couldn't find a clear example on how to return this data.  Here's my code:

```
- (NSString*) sendRequestToServer : (CLLocationCoordinate2D) location {
  NSLog(@"getting geo from server %@ %@ ", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.latitude],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.longitude]);
  __block long returnBytesSend = 0;
  __block long returnBytesTotal = 0;
  __block NSString* tempData = @"" ;
  __block BOOL foundNow = false;
  self.data = nil;

  for (NXOAuth2Account *account in [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accounts]) {

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [params setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.latitude]  forKey:   @"latitude"];
    [params setObject:  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.longitude] forKey:@"longitude" ];
    [params setObject: @"10" forKey:   @"radius" ];
    [params setObject: @"5" forKey: @"limit"];

    NXOAuth2Client *client =     [account oauthClient];
    NXOAuth2AccessToken *tokenData = [client accessToken];

    NSString * clientAccessToken = [tokenData accessToken];
    NSString * clientRefreshToken = [tokenData refreshToken];

    if (clientAccessToken && clientRefreshToken ){

        [NXOAuth2Request performMethod:@"GET"
                            onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.server.com/list"]
                       usingParameters: params
                           withAccount:account
                   sendProgressHandler:^(unsigned long long bytesSend, unsigned long long bytesTotal) {
                       returnBytesSend =  bytesSend ;
                       returnBytesTotal = bytesTotal;
                   }
                       responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData2, NSError *error){
                                  NSLog(@"FOUND DATA");
                            NSRange range = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] rangeOfString :  @"facebook_id"];
                           if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
                                tempData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]retain];
                               //NSLog(@"%@",  tempData);
                               self.data = [[tempData copy] autorelease];
                               foundData = true;

                           }
                       }];
    }
}

  return tempData;

}
```

I was trying to acces the data this way:

```
 @interface oAuthView : UIWebView
@property (nonatomic, strong) __block  NSString* data;
@property (nonatomic) __block BOOL foundData;
```

and in c++ like this:

```
    oAuthView *getWebView;
    getWebView =[[oAuthView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,40,300,400)];
    if ([getWebView foundData]  )  
    string dataS = string([[artPartView data] UTF8String]));
```

Comment: [class  foundData] is not valid C++ - could you explain how this is used? e.g. show us teh code here as well.

Comment: The class i'm accessing is obj-c. After that i access the data in c++.

Comment: How are you assigning to getWebView?

Comment: getWebView =[[oAuthView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,40,300,400)];
    [getWebView loadView];

Comment: Use cstringUsingEncoding: method to return a char* type through your method which is a array of char data type or perfectly valid c++ string class.

Comment: Forgot to tell that the bool crashes too. I was trying to access the bool and when the data is received, then read the bool. I'm accessing the nsstring this way: string dataS = string([[artPartView data] UTF8String]));

Comment: I guess you're running under ARC? Do you have strong reference to the objects in question anywhere else in your code? If not, they will be released. Try running with zombies enabled (Check under scheme settings > options > enable zombie objects)

Comment: also never seen __block qualifier on properties... not sure it makes sense since they're object properties. __block is for stack allocated variables you are altering from within a block.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080927/what-does-the-block-keyword-mean

Comment: does your code works without c++ ?

Comment: yes, perfectly. It receives the data, but just sometimes get a bad access at the bool and nsstring

Comment: I've allready tried multiple variations :(

Comment: Is there a different approach to avoid crashes and getting the data?

Comment: can you remove `__block` from the properties? it makes absolutely no sense.