# ios: Updating UITableView inside AFNetworking success callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to load data from API and show it inside a `UITableView`. I used `AFNetworking` for the network calls, but now I'm facing a problem: I can't access `myTableView` nor `self` inside the success block.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *myDataSource;

@synthesize featuredProductsTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NetworkManager *networkManager = [NetworkManager  getInstance];
    myDataSource = [NSMutableArray array]; 

    [networkManager getPath:@"example.com" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
        [myDataSource addObjectsFromArray:JSON];

        [myTableView reloadData]; 

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
}
```

Debugging the code shows that inside the block I can't access any of `self`, `myDataSource`, or `myTableView`.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: To access myDataSource you should use __block myDataSource = [NSMutableArray array]; , self and myTableView must be accessable

Comment: variables accessed inside a block without having being declared with __block prefix is a copy of the real variable

Comment: i changed it to  @property (nonatomic,retain) __block NSMutableArray *myDataSource; and still can't access any of them

Comment: Sorry where it is not accesable? Inside [networkManager getPath ... block ?

Comment: when trying to add the JSON to the dataSource and reloading the tableView, debugging shows that self is 0x00000000 and the others are invalid Expressions

Comment: @George ya some testing with __block fixed the problem, many thanks may you please add it as an answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use :

```
__block myDataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
```

You can also read:

[What does the "__block" keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080927/what-does-the-block-keyword-mean)

Comment: This is completely wrong. First, `__block` can only be applied to local variables. `myDataSource` is an instance variable. Second, even if it were a local variable, `__block` is only useful if the variable is assigned to. Nowhere is the variable assigned to other than when it is initialized before the block.

Comment: Read the question and comments before downvoting, as you see the question was edited

Comment: `myDataSource` was an instance variable in the original version

Answer (score -2):

Declare this right before your block:

```
__block typeof(self) this = self;
```

At least, this will allow you to reach `self` from inside the block, by calling it `this`.

Edit: that's not the way to go, my mistake. See [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api)

Comment: This is completely wrong. Of course you can access `self` from inside the block.

Comment: Then why does the static analyzer complain it's likely to lead to a retain cycle if I use `self` in (some) blocks? So I tried to teach myself and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api

Comment: it might lead to a retain cycle, but that does not mean you can't do it