# Is there an Objective-C property attribute that mimics the functionality of the __block keyword?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, objective-c-blocks

I want to make a property that allows a block to update its contents. For a typical variable (i.e. not auto-synthesized, etc), I would prefix the declaration with `__block`.

Is there a way to make a property that is able to be updated by a block?

Edit: Some answers say just to use the properties setter method. What I actually want to do is add objects to a mutable array, so I don't really want to create a new mutable array and set it back to the property using `setProperty:` or `.property =` each time. Is it possible to modify the property without all of these memory allocations?

Comment: As is noted in several answers below, you're free to modify a mutable array inside of a block without declaring anything with `__block`. What actual problem are you encountering?

Comment: @RobNapier The actual problem I'm encountering seems to be with my understanding of block handling. See my comments on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to put anything into a `@property` declaration. since they can be accessed and modified by blocks without any trouble. According to the documentation:

> Within the block object’s body of code, variables may be treated in
>   five different ways.
>
> You can reference three standard types of variable, just as you would
>   from a function:
>
> 1. Global variables, including static locals
> 2. Global functions (which aren’t technically variables)
> 3. Local variables and parameters from an enclosing scope
>
> Blocks also support two other types of variable:
>
> 1. At function level are `__block` variables. These are mutable within the
>      block (and the enclosing scope) and are preserved if any referencing
>      block is copied to the heap.
> 2. `const` imports.
>
> The following rules apply to variables used within a block:
>
> 1. Global variables are accessible, including static variables that
>      exist within the enclosing lexical scope.
> 2. Parameters passed to the block are accessible (just like parameters to a function).
> 3. Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are
>      captured as `const` variables.
>    Their values are taken at the point of
>      the block expression within the program. In nested blocks, the value
>      is captured from the nearest enclosing scope.
> 4. Variables local to the enclosing lexical scope declared with the
>      `__block` storage modifier are provided by reference and so are mutable.
>      Any changes are reflected in the enclosing lexical scope,
>      including any other blocks defined within the same enclosing lexical
>      scope.
> 5. Local variables declared within the lexical scope of the block,
>      which behave exactly like local variables in a function.
>    Each
>      invocation of the block provides a new copy of that variable. These
>      variables can in turn be used as const or by-reference variables in
>      blocks enclosed within the block.

Comment: How will the compiler know to add __block to the ivar? This SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7081005/953105) makes it seem necessary.

Comment: Based on these, it's implied that the compiler, by default, copies function variables that are not __block defined, but does not copy global/class-accessible variables. For some reason, I thought that *everything* was copied.

Comment: You are correct; it only copies automatic variables that lack the `__block` storage modifier.

Comment: Ivars fall under rule #5, because the block const-captures `self`, and not the ivar directly.  Ivars are then looked up via `self->_ivarName`.  So even though `self` is `const`, its members aren't, which is why you can reference ivars in a block without having to declare them as `__block`.

Comment: "they are global variables" what?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the right way to think about it. You want to modify an object, which has a property. So you capture the object in the block, and call its accessors (`setFoo:`) to modify the property.

---

EDIT: From the various edits, you may be confusing how ObjC objects work and how C++ works. ObjC only uses pointers to objects, seldom copies them, and lacks the concept of a `const` object (there are immutable objects, but it's just because they don't have mutators; you can't `const` a mutable object like you can in C++).

`__block` just means "this variable (not the object pointed to by it; this actual variable) should be passed by reference into the block rather than by value)." So when I say:

```
__block id foo;
```

this means that the `foo` pointer *itself* can be changed. It has nothing at all to do with whether the object pointed to by `foo` can be mutated. This makes no sense for a global or an ivar. ivars are implicitly struct fields. When you say `_ivar` inside a block, the compiler implicitly converts this to `self->_ivar` and then captures `self`. It does not capture `_ivar` (since that's just an offset into the `self` struct). It's better to do the same using accessors, since it's much more explicit what you're doing, and you can use `__weak` that way.

Comment: I don't understand your edits. If you want to add objects to a mutable array, just call `[[myObject someArray] addObject:foo]` (where `myObject` is whatever object you've captured in the block). What memory allocations are you talking about here?

Comment: People often use _ _block_ unnecessarily for mutable arrays / dictionaries. You can just outside the block write NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray array]; and use myArray inside the block. The block captures myArray - which is just a pointer to an instance of NSMutableArray. You can't modify myArray inside the block, but that's just the pointer. You _can_ modify the NSMutableArray object itself as much as you like, for example [myArray addObject:@"Hello"];. This adds an object to the array that myArray points to; it doesn't change myArray (the pointer).

Answer (score 3):

`__block` is used to declare **local variables** that a block might want to change.

Neither are properties local variables, nor is there a need to change a variable when all you want to do is add something to a mutable array. The variable does not change, it's the object's state behind the variable that changes.

Answer (score 2):

You use __block when you want to modify a variable within a block; in your case what you want to do is not modifying the variable(it will still point to the same `NSMutableArray`) but just sending a message to it(`addObject:`). You don't need __block for that.