# What's the best way to dispatch some task to a "background thread" and perform a task on the main thread when finished?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I am learning `GCD` and I am wondering if the following is OK or:
**is there a better way to do?**

I am also wondering if I need to weakify `self` in what follows. I am using `ARC`.

```
id someObject = [self getSomeObject] ;

dispatch_queue_t newThread = dispatch_queue_create("New thread", NULL) ;

dispatch_async(newThread, ^
               {
                   [self doSomeStuff] ;

                   [someObject doSomeStuffOnMyObject] ;

                   /*
                    Back on the main thread
                    */
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                  {
                                      [self doSomeStuffMore] ;

                                      [someObject doSomeStuffOnMyObjectMore] ;
                                  }) ;
               }) ;
```

So, if this is the good way to do, should I create a category over `NSObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common practice is what you have:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, flags), ^(void) {
    // code

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        // code
    });
});
```

If you plan on modifying `someObject` within the block and using it afterward then you should prefix it with `__block` - more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080927/what-does-the-block-keyword-mean)

```
__block id someObject = [self getSomeObject];
```

P.S. your semicolon style is unique :D

Comment: Thanks! Happy to do it well! My semi-colon style is the French style! (we put a space before ";")...