# how to copy ui image to another variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

i want to set uiimage to a variable outside the scope of function .i tried the code below  but it doesn't work . code below is used in custom uitable view cell class . so i just cannot alloc and init it . as this will cause to initialize it every time cell is displayed/ scrolled

```
 uiimage *img;
    [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendData.picUrl] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {

        img =image; ////this is not working !!



    }];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        [cell.profileImage setImage:img];   //and off course this wont work too

    });
```

Comment: could u post some code where that `UIImage *image1` is declared?

Comment: Maybe you need to initiate it before assign the UIImage value? Try UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just need to set `__block UIImage image = nil;`

Comment: replace this: uiimage *img;

Comment: it works :) but can u explain it a little why its working ? i am new to "blocks"

Comment: You can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7081005/3725351  And accept this answear

Comment: Essential is this part: When they are marked with __block, the modifications done inside the block are also visible outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the `image1` with any other initializing methods:
Try this one:

```
image1 = UIImage.init(CGImage:image.CGImage);
```

Initializer method will create new object as per [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithCGImage:) document.

I haven't tried it. Please try if it works. If not working just comment me, I may find other solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate image1 to make it work out of the function.try this

```
image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: image.CGImage];
```