# How to create an asynchronous while loop in xcode

Tags: objective-c

how can i add this piece of code inside an asynchronous block which keeps on running in the background?

```
for(int i=0;i<10; i++){
        carRPM = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        NSLog(@"Car RPM: %@",carRPM);
    }
```

Comment: Please be aware that none of your questions so far have had anything to do with the `xcode IDE` so please stop using that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to dispatch an asynchronous thread to execute your code from within a closure using the following syntax:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue ,^{
    for(int i=0;i<10; i++){
    carRPM = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    NSLog(@"Car RPM: %@",carRPM);
    }

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Update the UI

   });
});
```

**EDIT**: Updated my code to be more accurate for running on a separate thread as well as added a block from within the thread to update UI as you update the UI via the main thread.

Comment: No problem, I was assuming you were doing this in swift. I have approved your edits to convert the code to objective-c. Glad it worked out. If the question is complete and you see fit, please remember to accept the answer :).

Comment: I thought the OP wanted this to execute in a background thread, not the main thread?

Comment: @trojanfoe, good catch, I mistakenly pasted an example dispatching to the main queue. I have updated my answer to reflect this correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate thread to run your loop in by using GCD and using `dispatch_async()`.

```
// Create the new thread that you want to run the loop on.
dispatch_queue_t myLoopQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Loop Queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(myLoopQueue, ^{
    for(int i=0;i<10; i++) {
        carRPM = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        NSLog(@"Car RPM: %@",carRPM);
    }
});
```

I'll assume that you will want to use the value stored within `carRPM` sooner or later. So it would be wise to know that the final value of `carRPM` will be lost once the thread is finished. To be able to use the final value of `carRPM` that has been set within the block you'll need to mark `carRPM` with the keyword `__block`, checkout the explanation of this keyword [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080927/what-does-the-block-keyword-mean).

If you just use `dispatch_get_main_queue()` this will run your loop on the main thread and **NOT** on a separate thread.