# Behavior of __block modifier in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

We know `__block` makes blocks not retain the objects, but why this happens:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TestClass : NSObject

@end

@implementation TestClass

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"test class deinit..");
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    __block TestClass *testClass = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSLog(@"testClass: %@", testClass);
    });
}

@end
```

Output:

```
testClass: <TestClass: 0x6000000045e0>
test class deinit..
```

If the block doesn't retain `testClass`, shouldn't it be nil when we print it?

Comment: It's `__weak` that doesn't retain the object, not `__block`. Anyway, your `aBlock();` call is in the same `viewDidLoad` block as `testClass`, so it's still retained by it. And even if it were somehow deallocated (by making the call async?), it wouldn't magically turn the pointer to nil.

Comment: @Cœur sorry I updated the question, there was a typo in the original code. In the updated code, `testClass` is still not nil

Comment: If you're using ARC, `__block` only still retains the pointer. Maybe `__weak __block` could help? And try some `@autoreleasepool` to trigger the dealloc early.

Comment: Indeed, this is not what `__block` does: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080927/what-does-the-block-keyword-mean. You need `__weak` in order to keep the value from getting retained. The thing you have to keep in mind with `__weak` is that for it to not be `nil`, the value it points to has to have a reference somewhere else. `__weak TestClass *testClass = [[TestClass alloc] init]` will immediately deallocate your object because there are no strong references to it.

Comment: I understand what __weak does. The question I am asking here is different though. I am wondering why `__block TestClass *testClass = [[TestClass alloc] init];` doesn't make `testClass` deallocated inside the block, while `TestClass *testClass = [[TestClass alloc] init];` makes the block deallocated inside the block.

Comment: With no `__block` it's because you're a creating a local variable, so it will be deallocated at the end of the scope, here the closing `}` of `viewDidLoad`. With the `__block` it's "hey keep it a little longer for the "async blocks" (usually async ones) to complete.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080927/what-does-the-block-keyword-mean